# i can't apply labelencoder to array of bool

Tags: python, machine-learning, spyder, data-preprocessing, label-encoding

I am on a machine learning project. I did import all libraries. I took one column of data(this column is array of bool) and i want to apply it labelencoder.
Here is my whole code.

```
data = pd.read_csv('odev_tenis.csv')

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

ruzgar = data.iloc[:,3:4].values #the column i want to apply labelencoder
ruzgar[:,3:4] = le.fit_transform(data.iloc[:,3:4])
```

And here is the error i got.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (14,) into shape (14,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.iloc[:,3:4]` does not return a `Series` but a `DataFrame` of 1 column. Try:

```
ruzgar = le.fit_transform(data.iloc[:, 3])
```

Comment: Gave this error:
"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'"

I did fix it with first comment also.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my error.